Postgres logical replication, it is impossible to restart slot after copyDone
In the replication client, I sometimes need to exit copy mode to perform SQL queries, and then return to slot replication, but when I re-issue the slot start command, I get a response from the server CopyBothResponse and immediately after it CommandComplete.
What am I doing wrong, why does the server immediately end the COPY mode after restarting the slot?
Here is a simplified dialog between the client and the backend:
FE -> CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT "name" TEMPORARY LOGICAL pgoutput (SNAPSHOT 'nothing')
FE -> START_REPLICATION SLOT "name" LOGICAL 0/0 (
        binary 'on',
        messages 'on',
        proto_version '1',
        publication_names 'pub'
      )
BE <- CopyBothResponse
BE <- CopyData
  ...
FE -> CopyDone
BE <- CommandComplete
BE <- ReadyForQuery
FE -> Query SELECT...
BE <- ReadyForQuery
FE -> START_REPLICATION SLOT "name" LOGICAL 0/0 (
        binary 'on',
        messages 'on',
        proto_version '1',
        publication_names 'pub'
      )
BE <- CommandComplete
BE <- ReadyForQuery


I didn't test, but the documentation says: "Finally, the server sends two CommandComplete messages (one that ends the CopyData and the other ends the START_REPLICATION itself), and is ready to accept a new command."

The documentation describes the behavior when the server successfully completes replication, this happens in two cases, the phishing LSN is reached or the client sent a CopyDone message to the server, this is correct, but why when I start a slot a second time with an LSN in which there are unsent events and I did not send CopyDone the second time, the server completes replication in response to me, instead of switching to COPY mode

I just thought it might be relevant, as you only expect one CommandComplete, and the second one seems to come as a surprise.

@laurenz-albe No, it looks like this is a bug in the walsender.c code
https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/replication/walsender.c#L906
the streamingDoneReceiving variable is redefined in false, only when starting physical replication, this is not the case when starting logical replication, so logical replication cannot restart, it looks like a bug

Quite possible. You should report it on pgsql-hackers or pgsql-bugs.

Done https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/18754-e49e7bda4eb683d9%40postgresql.org
